# leadingSwipeActions conflict with custom gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gesture

I have a view on tableView and added `UIPanGestireRecognizer` to that view.

And on my tableView I have a swipe action realized with

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

but it works bad. Most of the time my panGesture works instead of swipe action. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement UIGestureDelegate and check.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if gestureRecognizer.view == YourView {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Yes, it helped. I subscribed my class to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and implemented this method, and I have a little bit different logic)

`open func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, inView view: UIView) -> Bool {
        let translation = (gestureRecognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).translation(in: view)
        if canMoveMenu(point: translation){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }`